# Image effects with rotation and pinch to zoom using GLSurfaceView Android

Tags: android, image-rotation, pinchzoom, glsurfaceview

I was developing an application to apply effects/rotation/pinch to zoom in-out functionality on image. I have downloaded demo application from https://github.com/Grishu/ImageEffects.

It works well, now my problems/questions are as below:

1. Apply multiple effects on images with progress change value (e.g. First apply brightness effect and result of this apply another effect say "contrast".)

   **- problem:** in code effect always apply on original image. So change in code to apply effect on final image like,

   ```
   if(isApplyEffectOnOriginalImage){//call first time only         
       mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
   }else{
       mEffect.apply(mTextures[1], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
   }
   ```

   Now, if apply brightness effect on progress change first time it works fine. But if I apply the same or other(contrast) effect, now I think on progress change effect apply on mTextures[1] and result set in mTextures[1], so is it possible to create temporary mTextures[2] to store mTextures[1] initially and when user change the progress value apply effect on mTextures[2] and set result on mTextures[1] like happen in if condition.
2. How to apply pinch to zoom on images
3. Rotation issue: I was rotating image at 90 angle clockwise, just by setting values(90,180,270, etc.), but the problem is when rotating image from 90 to 180, image rendering is not properly.
   see

A) 0 angle image

[image: 0 angle image]

B) 90 angle image

[image: 90 angle image]

C) 180 angle image

[image: 180 angle image]

Answer (score 5):

I've modified Grishu's demo project: **[here's a Screen Recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkzTRxMXh1o)**, then some explanation:
[image]

*(Image rotated, with three effect applied - flip horizontal, crossprocess, fisheye)*

1) For applying the effect on the result, your suggestion works fine. I don't really understand what you mean by ,,progress change effect''. Do you want to tune parameters of the effect?

2) To have gestures you should extend `GLSurfaceView` and implement `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` and/or `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener` depending on your needs. See TouchGLView here: [Source](https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/GDC11Activity.java), or the snippet below:

```
private class TouchGLView extends GLSurfaceView
        implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {
    private TextureRenderer mRenderer;
    private GestureDetector mTapDetector;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mLastSpan = 0;

    TouchGLView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        // Use Android's built-in gesture detectors to detect
        // which touch event the user is doing.
        mTapDetector = new GestureDetector(c, this);
        mTapDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(c, this);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new TextureRenderer(c);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent e) {
        // Forward touch events to the gesture detectors.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        mTapDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            final float dx, final float dy) {
        // Forward the drag event to the renderer.
        queueEvent(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRenderer.drag(dx, dy);
            }});
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // Forward the scale event to the renderer.
        final float amount = detector.getCurrentSpan() - mLastSpan;
        queueEvent(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRenderer.zoom(amount);
            }});
        mLastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

3) You can rotate the image by modifying the vertex coordinates and taking viewports into account.
Also, you can apply *different* rotations. You can rotate (and zoom) the view (vertex coordinates) itself (which does not affect the original texture buffer) or you can *rotate* pixels in the texture buffer (which is easy for 90°, 180°, etc) and then update your vertex coordinates to match the new image width/height.

Here's an example for manipulating with the vertex coords:

```
private void computeOutputVertices() {
    if (mPosVertices != null) {
        float imgAspectRatio = mTexWidth / (float)mTexHeight;
        float viewAspectRatio = mViewWidth / (float)mViewHeight;
        float x0, y0, x1, y1;
        // Set initial vertex coords based in texture aspect
        if (imgAspectRatio > 1.0f) {
            x0 = -1.0f ;
            y0 = -1.0f / imgAspectRatio;
            x1 = 1.0f ;
            y1 = 1.0f / imgAspectRatio;
        } else {
            x0 = -1.0f *imgAspectRatio;
            y0 = -1.0f;
            x1 = 1.0f *imgAspectRatio;
            y1 = 1.0f;
        }
        float[] coords = new float[] { x0, y0, x1, y0, x0, y1, x1, y1 };
        // Scale coordinates with mZoom
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            coords[i] *= mZoom;
        }
        // Rotate coordinates with mRot
        float cosa = (float)Math.cos(mRot);
        float sina = (float)Math.sin(mRot);
        float x,y;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2) {
            x = coords[i]; y = coords[i+1];
            coords[i]   = cosa*x-sina*y;
            coords[i+1] = sina*x+cosa*y;
        }
        // Finally scale again to match screen aspect
        if (viewAspectRatio > 1.0f) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i+=2) {
                coords[i] = coords[i]/viewAspectRatio;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i+=2) {
                coords[i] = coords[i]*viewAspectRatio;
            }
        }
        mPosVertices.put(coords).position(0);
    }
}
```

I suggest you to dive into OpenGL matrices and do all these transformations using them.

I've modified `TextureRenderer` class to implement `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, and changed renderMode to `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY`.

Finally, the [source for the modified demo is here](https://github.com/Gyebro/android-demos/tree/master/EffectsFilter).

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply
1) is it possible to apply effect on seekbar's progress change? as it work file first time when i apply effect from "mTextures[0]" to "mTextures[1]" and rander textureId "mTextures[1]". after apply effect first time, if apply second effect say "CONTRAST" on seekbar's progress change then effect apply from "mTextures[1]" to
"mTextures[1]" and render textureId "mTextures[1]". you will notice that image will be black out.

Comment: I think if i reuse "mTextures[1]" as fresh texture. will solved my problem, but don't know how to re-use it.
2) Pinch to zoom:works well, but the problem with scrolling image. any idea?
3) Rotation: works well. is it possible to apply rotation using build in roration effect at (90,180,270,...)clockwise.

Comment: Guys rotation and zoom works well but Drag is not working ...how to solve.