# Zooming and translate GPUImageView android

Tags: android, android-gpuimageview

I want to GPUimageView able to pinch and zoom. I found example in [Image effects with rotation and pinch to zoom using GLSurfaceView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763160/image-effects-with-rotation-and-pinch-to-zoom-using-glsurfaceview-android)

So, edit in GPUImageRenderer

```
private void adjustImageScaling() {
        float outputWidth = mOutputWidth;
        float outputHeight = mOutputHeight;
        if (mRotation == Rotation.ROTATION_270 || mRotation == Rotation.ROTATION_90) {
            outputWidth = mOutputHeight;
            outputHeight = mOutputWidth;
        }

        float ratio1 = outputWidth / mImageWidth;
        float ratio2 = outputHeight / mImageHeight;
        float ratioMax = Math.max(ratio1, ratio2);
        int imageWidthNew = Math.round(mImageWidth * ratioMax);
        int imageHeightNew = Math.round(mImageHeight * ratioMax);

        float ratioWidth = imageWidthNew / outputWidth;
        float ratioHeight = imageHeightNew / outputHeight;

        float[] cube = CUBE;
        float[] textureCords = TextureRotationUtil.getRotation(mRotation, mFlipHorizontal, mFlipVertical);
        if (mScaleType == GPUImage.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) {
            float distHorizontal = (1 - 1 / ratioWidth) / 2;
            float distVertical = (1 - 1 / ratioHeight) / 2;
            textureCords = new float[]{
                    addDistance(textureCords[0], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[1], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[2], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[3], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[4], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[5], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[6], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[7], distVertical),
            };
        } else {
            cube = new float[]{
                    CUBE[0] / ratioHeight, CUBE[1] / ratioWidth,
                    CUBE[2] / ratioHeight, CUBE[3] / ratioWidth,
                    CUBE[4] / ratioHeight, CUBE[5] / ratioWidth,
                    CUBE[6] / ratioHeight, CUBE[7] / ratioWidth,
            };
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                cube [i] *= mZoom;
            }
        mGLCubeBuffer.clear();
        mGLCubeBuffer.put(cube).position(0);
        mGLTextureBuffer.clear();
        mGLTextureBuffer.put(textureCords).position(0);
    }
```

I added code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                cude[i] *= mZoom;
            }
```

above glCubeBuffer.clear(); but does not work.
Please help me right implements.
Thank you

**EDIT: Problem solved:**
setRendermode from dirty to setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
and it works

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Can you help me to resolve the same? For me GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

setRendermode from dirty to setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
and it works